# Handling null array in a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query with a contains with an array of values. The issue I am having is if the array is empty/null it breaks my query. How to I handle this within the linq query. My other option was to check the length of the array before executing the linq query but was wondering if its possible to include this check within the query.

Code

```
// Properties
public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
public string[] SubCategory { get; set; }

var entities = await _DbContext.MasterProductView
                                    .Where(e => e.BusinessUnit == query.BusinessUnit &&
                                                e.Category == query.Category &&
                                                query.SubCategory.Contains(e.SubCategory))
                                    .Select(e => new OptionDto() { Value = e.Brand, Label = e.Brand })
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .OrderBy(e => e.Label)
                                    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var entities = await _DbContext.MasterProductView
                                .Where(e => query.SubCategory.Any() ? e.BusinessUnit == query.BusinessUnit &&
                                            e.Category == query.Category &&
                                            query.SubCategory.Contains(e.SubCategory) : e.BusinessUnit == query.BusinessUnit &&
                                            e.Category == query.Category)
                                .Select(e => new OptionDto() { Value = e.Brand, Label = e.Brand })
                                .Distinct()
                                .OrderBy(e => e.Label)
                                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have problem with empty array, only null ones. You can use the [null-conditional operator `?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) in conjunction with the [null-coalescing operator `??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

```
// Properties
public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
public string[] SubCategory { get; set; }

var entities = await _DbContext.MasterProductView
    .Where(e => e.BusinessUnit == query.BusinessUnit &&
                e.Category == query.Category &&
                query.SubCategory?.Contains(e.SubCategory) ?? false)
    .Select(e => new OptionDto() { Value = e.Brand, Label = e.Brand })
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(e => e.Label)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```